# Having different count per key in jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jsonb

I have values in a table called Translation, that contains for every values per example:

```
=> {"fr"=>"Jaune", "de"=>"", "en"=>"", "bg"=>"", "hr"=>"", "es"=>"", "hu"=>"", "it"=>"", "lt"=>"", "lv"=>"", "nl"=>"", "pl"=>"", "pt"=>"", "ro"=>"", "cs"=>""}
```

and I'm looking to get the the number of the translation for each language: 
I'm trying :

```
Translation.where("values->>'fr' IS NOT NULL").count
```

but it giving me 0, which is not correct, do anyone knows how to do it correctly?

Comment: It's not clear why you look for `'fr'`, since is a key of an hash so it can not be repeated. Anyway considering `translations` as an hash, can you use this?`translations.count { |k, v| k if !v.empty? }`

Comment: It's unique in every translations, but in another translations it may exists or not. translations have a key (which the word I want to translate) and a value that contains the translations in the languages available. in the example I gave:  translations ( key : yellow, values:  {"fr"=>"Jaune", "de"=>"", "en"=>"", "bg"=>"", "hr"=>"", "es"=>"", "hu"=>"", "it"=>"", "lt"=>"", "lv"=>"", "nl"=>"", "pl"=>"", "pt"=>"", "ro"=>"", "cs"=>""} )

Comment: I think the key is missing. So, for example you want to know in how many languages the word "yellow" (or whatever word) is translated? `translations["yellow"].count { |k, v| k if !v.empty? }`

Comment: No, I want to know in a language selected how many words are translated,  for the example i gave {"fr"=>"Jaune", "de"=>""... }  ("", or northing means it's untranslated

Comment: Ok, maybe now it's clearer. You have a nested hash where the first level keys are words and second level keys are languages? In that case, try: `translations.reject { |k, v| (v["fr"] == "") }.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the keys that don't have values, still exist in the json, so "is not null" will return all of them because the key exist. you have two options here, you can remove the empty keys from the database, so not null will work, or, change it to see if the key is empty

You can do it like this

```
Translation.where("values->>'fr' <> ''").count
```

and it will work with the structure that you have right now.

Comment: It gives me 0, while for fr I have a plenty of existant translations

Comment: it seems like a data problem then. can you add to the question the result to 'Translation.last(3)' for example

Comment: I resolved it, it was the store coder(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor) the probleme, I had to use store_accessor. and yeah you're right i'll need to clear the empty translation, in a before_validation